# Creating a new customer with WooCommerce API needs password confirmation

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

When sending this POST data

```
{
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "username": "john.doe",
  "password": "Hashem123123@@@",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  }
}
```

to https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers with basic authentication.
I have the following response

```
{
    "code": "error_confirm_password_empty",
    "message": "Invalid confirmation password",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** 
This registration is supposed to be submitted to the admin to be approved. Maybe this end-point is for signing up directly and there is another end-point for submitting the registration to be approved (?) I checked WooCommerce [Docs](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#introduction) and it seems there is nothing of the sort.

Comment: I don't see password in the documentation, you can just remove that and test again

Comment: @Akam documentation is not up-to-date. without the password field you will get {
    "code": "rest_missing_callback_param",
    "message": "مُعاملات مفقودة: password",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "params": [
            "password"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Above code has no issue its working for me and created customer also with basic authentication see (https://prnt.sc/q95wfo)

Comment: @KrishnaSavani is your new customer waiting for admin approval now? or it is registered directly?

Comment: registered directly

Comment: @KrishnaSavani Did you add a field "password" to the request body?

Comment: yes same json of yours i have added

Answer (score -1):

You can just add the following item along with existing array.

```
{
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "username": "john.doe",
    "password": "Hashem123123@@@",
    "confirm_password": "Hashem123123@@@",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  }
}
```